# error talking to parse servers on parse new

Tags: windows, parse-platform

I am trying to create a parse project.

I have installed parse.Copied `parse.exe` and `ParseConsole.exe` in System 32 and SystemWow64 as well.

I am on a `64 but operating system`.

This is what I get :

[image: screenshot]

I have tried changing the path from System32 to SysWOW64 and then running `ParseConsole.exe` but no luck.

Comment: did you find a solution?